# XMLHttpRequest delays in starting session

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

Iam beginner to ajax. When i used ajax for search function it delays in starting operation

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?gender="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

When the radio button on the `product.php` page is clicked `showUser(str)` is called. The value is accessed in variable `gender` in `getuser.php` and the session started with the value in varible `gender` and the sql query is executed using the session variable

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE gender = '".$_SESSION['gender']."'";
```

and the values are echoe in `txtHint` div. My problem is When i clicked the radio butoon for the very first time the function is called, but the value is not echoed in page.When i reloaded the page and try it again it works fine.Please help to fix this

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in

```
window.onload
```

function. Like this

```
window.onload = function() {
      function showUser(str)
{
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?gender="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
};
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response.I used your code, But it's not working for me :( @chandresh_cool